# Rotate video in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, textureview

I have problem with `rotate video` in `Android`. I used `TextureView` to rotate the video but it didn't work fine. It show black screen on device `Android 4.2.2`. Any body have idea for rotate video? such as use `SurfaceView`. Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Video in Android can be rotated by using the following code:

```
videoView.setRotation(90f);
 videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
 videoView.start();
```

I used the above code to rotate a video for my app

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you but I use VideoView and setRotation(90f) for it. It can't play video. It show black screen. If you have solution. Please help me.